# I'm wondering if it is possible to apply dns settings to different bands on a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router

Is it possible to use distinct dns setting for each band used on a dual band router? I can't seem to find anything online that describes this facility. Ideally the solution I'm looking to put in place is 2 networks in my home one which routes traffic via a specific dns server. Ideally I don't want to have a second router connected just to setup the second (dns enabled) network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be pedantic, it is possible, but not with most home routers.  Any business grade wireless acess point will expose the 2.4 GHz and 5.8 GHz radios as separate interfaces, which can further be divided into multiple virtual interfaces, all of which can be bridged to separate VLANs.

That being said, a rinky-dink Netgear is not going to expose such functionality in the web UI.

DD WRT, on the other hand, is happy to lend you a gun and point it at your foot — they even [have a wiki page explaining how to do it](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Multiple_WLANs).

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, will give dd-wrt a shot. Am now off find out which modern routers are dd-wrt compatible.